# LEFT OUTER JOIN vs NOT EXISTS syntax with multiple tables

Tags: syntax, sql-server-2012, left-join, ssrs-2012, not-exists

I am doing some performance troubleshooting on my SSRS native instance. I have what I hope is a simple syntax issue. I am troubleshooting execution plans when using LEFT OUTER JOIN and NOT EXISTS. I know the difference between the two and hope that maybe NOT EXISTS is my solution, however I have one problem. Here is my query.

```
SELECT [Facility]
  ,[CategoryDesc]
  ,[SubCategoryDesc]
  ,[ItemKey]
  ,[ItemDesc]
  ,[HeadCount]
  ,[Group]
  ,[Group Name]
  ,[CustomerKey]
  ,[Customer]
  ,[InvoiceNo]
  ,[InvoiceDate]
  ,[OrderNo]
  ,[OrderDate]
  ,[FiscalYear]
  ,[Quarter]
  ,[WeekNo]
  ,[SalesmanID]
  ,[Salesman]
  ,[ReasonCodeKey]
  ,[Weight]
  ,[Box]
  ,[Value]
  ,[OrderStatus]
  ,[PONumber]
  ,[SubCategoryKey]
  ,[DispatchCenterOrderKey]
  ,[PromotionFlag]
  ,[CategoryKey]
  ,b.UserID
FROM [FinancialData].[dbo].[FactSalesHistoryDetail] a
LEFT OUTER JOIN [FinancialData].[dbo].[DimSalesRepUserIDMap] b on b.SalesRepID = a.SalesmanID
```

I am hoping to use this instead:

```
SELECT [Facility]
  ,[CategoryDesc]
  ,[SubCategoryDesc]
  ,[ItemKey]
  ,[ItemDesc]
  ,[HeadCount]
  ,[Group]
  ,[Group Name]
  ,[CustomerKey]
  ,[Customer]
  ,[InvoiceNo]
  ,[InvoiceDate]
  ,[OrderNo]
  ,[OrderDate]
  ,[FiscalYear]
  ,[Quarter]
  ,[WeekNo]
  ,[SalesmanID]
  ,[Salesman]
  ,[ReasonCodeKey]
  ,[Weight]
  ,[Box]
  ,[Value]
  ,[OrderStatus]
  ,[PONumber]
  ,[SubCategoryKey]
  ,[DispatchCenterOrderKey]
  ,[PromotionFlag]
  ,[CategoryKey]
  ,b.UserID
  FROM [FinancialData].[dbo].[FactSalesHistoryDetail] a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FinancialData.dbo.DimSalesRepUserIDMap b WHERE b.SalesRepID = a.SalesmanID)
```

The problem is that the very last column "b.UserID" uses the LEFT OUTER JOIN to get it's alias. When use the last query, I get "the multi-part identifier "b.UserID" could not be bound. Obviously this is because I have removed the call to this table. If I include it this way... it takes far far too long and not what I am expecting to receive.

```
 FROM [FinancialData].[dbo].[FactSalesHistoryDetail] a,     FinancialData.dbo.DimSalesRepUserIDMap b
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FinancialData.dbo.DimSalesRepUserIDMap b WHERE b.SalesRepID = a.SalesmanID)
```

So the question is how do I format this so that I am optimizing the performance with NOT EXISTS or EXISTS, while also referencing multiple columns from other tables?

Comment: if you need to include b.UserID then you have no choice but to do a join. even [FinancialData].[dbo].[FactSalesHistoryDetail] a,     FinancialData.dbo.DimSalesRepUserIDMap b is an older syntax of joining. I would suggest using your original LEFT OUTER JOIN and use execution plan to determine if you need any indexes placed on the table. I think SalesRepID  will need to be indexed on both tables and the include part of the index should include the columns in the SELECT part of the statement. Good luck!

Comment: Specifying OUTER following a LEFT is optional syntax. Both LEFT and LEFT OUTER mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Left join is the best option at this juncture. The last query will produce results but will have performance impact. Btw, did you try cross join?

Comment: I have not, can you show me the syntax for this Ajith?